# Regarding value of Map to be of type Map internally

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a class

```
private String patientId;
private String scriptinfo;
private Phone No.;


Now I have the hashMap..
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
```

Now I want that there should be single key of hashmap let  say 'A' is the key which I will pass but the value 
is of again Map type, some thing like this..

```
hm.put ("A", <<value should be of Map type>>)
```

in that Map type value again I keep all the information like patientId,scriptinfo,Phone No. and I want patient id 
is to be the key of that Map, Please advise how to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

Design your class like below.

```
class MyClass{

private String patientId;
private String scriptinfo;
private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Then use this in Map.

```
Map<String, Map<String, MyClass>> hm = new HashMap<String,Map<String,MyClass>>();

    Map<String, MyClass> data = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
    data.put(patientId, new MyClass(patientId,scriptinfo,phoneNumber));
    ...
    hm.put("A", data);
```

While getting MyClass information you can use something like this.

```
MyClass mc=hm.get("A").get("patientId");
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit overdone? In this case, `hm` should be defined as `Map<String, MyClass>`.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen , I second with you but poster wants this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> hm = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("patientId", patientId);
...
hm.put("A", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Type1, Type2> hm = new HashMap<>(); 
HashMap<Type1, Type2> hm2 = new HashMap<>();
hm2.put(val1, val2);
hm.put ("A", hm2);
```